# Reference first value in ternary operator

Tags: python, python-3.x

Very often I find myself writing a ternary operator equivalent to the following

```py
var = a if returnsBool(a) else b
```

with `returnsBool` returning a boolean value depending on the value of `a`.

When `a` is lengthier variable it starts to look ugly and 'unpythonic'. Is there a way to reference `a` in the conditional part (`returnsBool(a)`) of the statement so you don't have to write `a` twice?

Or is there a better approach for this case, which is also useful for list comprehensions?

Comment: if conversion of bool from `a` respects the "truthy" or "falsy" value you could just write `var = a or b`. If `a` is a class type, just implement `__bool__` method and you can do that too.

Comment: you can also store the result of your lengthy variable to … `a`

Comment: What about `def boolOrDefault(a, b): return a if returnsBool(a) else b`? Functions are there to remove code duplication

Comment: Store the `a` expression in a variable first.

Comment: If the line gets too long, why not go with a classic `if` block?
Normally I assign var to b and only overwrite if if the condition is met. Saves a line :-)

Comment: But you can't just do an assignment from while building a list with a list comprehension, unless i'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @Caramiriel that's too specific but i guess i could do something like `def ternaryDependingOnFunc(a, b, func): return a if func(a) else b`.

Comment: Then just out this logic in a function and use that function in the list comprehension. The whole point of list comprehensions and conditional expressions is to *improve readability* if it's not doing that don't use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:=` "walrus" [assignment operator](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) that was introduced in Python 3.8:

```
def returnsBool(a):
    return bool(a)

reallylengthiervariablename = 42
b = 2

var = a if returnsBool(a := reallylengthiervariablename) else b
print(f'{var=}')  # -> var=42
```

Comment: This is probably the closest solution to what i had in mind, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `a` itself cannot be a "falsy" value, you could change your `returnsBool` to return `a` / `None` instead of `True` / `False`.

Then you could write:

```
var = maybe(a) or b
```

Otherwise, defining your own ternary seems like the best bet:

```
def conditional(func, a, b):
    return a if func(a) else b
```

And you could customize it for specific conditions using `partial`:

```
from functools import partial
some_cond = partial(conditional, returnsBool)
vars = [some_cond(a, b) for a, b in whatever]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not-very-idiomatic way of doing it, but it works; the `next` function can take a second argument which is returned in case the first argument is an empty iterator.

```py
>>> def is_even(x): return x % 2 == 0
... 
>>> very_long_variable_name = 12
>>> next(filter(is_even, [very_long_variable_name]), 'default')
12
>>> very_long_variable_name = 13
>>> next(filter(is_even, [very_long_variable_name]), 'default')
'default'
```

If you find yourself having to do this often, it may be worth writing a helper function, so that you can write e.g. `if_else(is_even, very_long_variable_name, 'default')`.

```py
def if_else(predicate, a, b):
    return a if predicate(a) else b
```